# Current & BEMF Measurement with LP Filter - Determining Cut-Off Frequency

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, low-pass

I am analyzing the BEMF and current sensing circuits of the ST Microelectronics demo board STEVAL-ESC001V1 as I am creating my own ESC based in part on this design.

My application will use a 4S lipo battery (16.8Vdc max), and a PWM frequency of 30kHz.  Based on measurements made using this and another ESC, my maximum sinusoidal current/voltage frequency is 2.5kHz which corresponds to the BLDC motor maximum speed.

The BEMF circuit in ST Micro's design consists of a voltage divider with a capacitor across the output as shown here.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOmD4s.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Aside from the ugly divider ratio, this level of capacitance serves only to attenuate and phase shift the output voltage at 2.5kHz.  I was thinking to use a 6:1 divider ratio to make better use of my ADC and a 100pF capacitor which won't attenuate or phase shift my signal (as much).

The current sensing circuit in ST Micro's design consists of an opamp circuit with a LP filter on the non-inverting input; and if desired a capacitor across the feedback resistor for additional filtering.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKPmo7.png)</sup>

The cut-off frequency of the LP filter on the non-inverting input is 1/(2 x PI x 787 x 680p) = 297kHz.  The cut-off frequency in the feedback loop is fc = 1/(2 x PI x 13k x 100p) = 122kHz.

Knowing the PWM frequency is 30kHz, and that likely noise to be filtered (due to dv/dt) will be at or around this frequency (correct me if I am wrong), why are they filtering at significantly much higher frequencies?

How should I be calculating my cut-off frequency (for both circuits), or is there a rule of thumb for determining the cut-off frequency in this application that I should abide by for relatively good or better performance?

As an FYI both circuits feed to ADC inputs on a STM32F303CB MCU.  I plan to buffer the BEMF signal prior to the ADC input.

Thank you,

Mike

Comment: With regards to the current bandwidth: I have this trick where I pass in full bandwidth current measurements and trigger an ADC conversion with the PWM module. It worked well but unfortunately I don’t remember the mathematical details or why I did it this way. Check the ST code for a similar trick?

Comment: Brian I will look into this.  I think this may be something they do.